# A simple event listener in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a small app that I don't see it growing beyond a couple of pages so for an event, I decided to have the event in the router `web.php`

This is the code

```
Event::listen('simpleEvent', function($user){ 
    $user->last_login = new DateTime;
     $user->save();
});
```

I want to use the event on a particular method

```
public function getLogin(){
    $user = User::find(1);
    $device = $agent->device();
    $platform = $agent->platform();
    $browser = $agent->browser();
    $ip = Request::ip();
    Event::fire('simpleEvent','[$user]);    
}
```

My question is, how do I pass the variables from `getLogin` to the event in the router?. Right now I am only passing the user

Comment: You can still pass your variables as an array, you then need to register them correctly in your listener, https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/events#defining-listeners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the data you need to pass in an array.

```
Event::listen('simpleEvent', function($data) {
    // dd($data);
});

public function getLogin()
{
    $user = User::find(1);
    $device = $agent->device();
    $platform = $agent->platform();
    $browser = $agent->browser();
    $ip = Request::ip();

    $data = compact('user', 'device', 'platform', 'browser', 'ip');

    Event::fire('simpleEvent', $data);
}
```